# Problem with slider and gesture detector flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, gesture, gesturedetector

I have three sliders on one screen. I use a slider to set the numeric values above them. The total sum of these values must be 100. If the first two values add up to e.g. 60, then the values above the third slider should be 40. And, accordingly, the height of the third slider is limited to 40%. In normal or slow mode everything works correctly, but if you move the slider sharply, the slider will easily jump over the 40% mark. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks
I used onVerticalDragUpdate, onVerticalDragEnd

Comment: can you please post your code that you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.